# Unable to Drop on scroll hidden droppables using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have list of droppable item and that container has scroll bar after some height,

when scroll bar comes then some droppable get hiddens and gets visable only on scroll down.

Because of this I cant drop on last droppable in given demo 'Drop Header 6'.

how do I achive when draggable is selected and i can scroll down and drop on last droppable items.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#dragLi > li").draggable({helper: "clone"});
            $( ".reviewersListDv > div" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
             (ui.helper).remove(); //destroy clone
            $(ui.draggable).remove(); //remove from list   
            $(this).find('.parallelSectContent').show();
            $( this ).empty().append( 'Droped');        
        }
            });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6jjR2/55/)